# Copying text line for line, using Scanner and FileWriter, Not appending

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, filewriter, printwriter

At a loss here. Been toying around with this trying to figure out how to copy a single string, line for line and append that into a copy. The copy is deleted if it exists, created if it doesn't, and I can see every line of text appear in the console, but it won't append into the new copy.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FriendListCopy
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String str;
    File file = new File("FriendList.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    File newFile = new File("FriendListCopy.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("FriendListCopy.txt", true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
    if(file.exists()) 
    {
        if(newFile.exists())
            newFile.delete();
        if(!newFile.exists())
            newFile.createNewFile();
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            str = inputFile.nextLine();
            pw.println(str);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        inputFile.close();
        pw.close();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    inputFile.close();
    pw.close();
    fw.close();
    }
}
```

Ignore all the close statements, I was just experimenting.
I have a feeling that this method can't be used, but maybe I'm just overlooking something. Thank you for any help you can provide.
Using Linux, if that's any help. Permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1  users 1724 Oct 23 11:51 FriendList.class
-rw-r--r-- 1  users 1197 Oct 23 15:52 FriendListCopy.class
-rw-r--r-- 1  users  761 Oct 23 15:49 FriendListCopy.java
-rw-r--r-- 1  users    0 Oct 23 15:51 FriendListCopy.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1  users 1124 Oct 23 11:37 FriendList.java
-rw-r--r-- 1  users   46 Oct 23 11:27 FriendList.txt
```

Comment: Well, *"but it won't append into the new copy"* works fine for me. The copy doesn't contain the content of "FriendList.txt" twice after running the programm a second time?

Comment: No it should delete a copy if it exists, and then create a new one. I'm not getting a single line on my copy file

Comment: *"No it should delete a copy if it exists, and then create a new one."* Well, it is obvious that this won't work, because you already opened that file for writting, so how should your program be able to delete it? This *"I'm not getting a single line on my copy file "* is something different. ... but again, it worked fine for me.

Comment: The call in the while loop should work as long as the file exists, I think.

Comment: If it's working for everyone else I suppose it's a permissions issue.

Comment: I would suggest two things: use [`java.nio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) classes instead of `File`. They provide a much better handling for files. For example: you never noticed that `newFile.delete()` fails, because it does that silently (it returns `false`). And try to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), because that makes it easier to close resources (avoids these `close` calls). Please update your question after the changes and if it still doesn't work :).

Comment: I'll be sure to take that in consideration! I'm in an intro to Java class so we need to sort of stay in the confines of io and beginner stuff. I do however enjoy exploring other more effective options, and will attempt this on my own time. :) Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the file exists/delete/create nonsense. `new FileWriter()` has already done all that. Even if you had done it in the right order you would still be duplicating everything.

If you're a beginner don't complicate your life with NIO yet.